# Oracle - update join - non key-preserved table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I'm trying to replicate an Ingres "update tbl1 from tbl2" command, which doesn't exactly exist in Oracle.

So I use "update (select tbl1 join tbl2...)" command.  Both tables have primary keys defined and I *thought* that my join was uniquely identifying rows, but I'm still getting "ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table".

Here are suitably anonymized table definitions and the update I'm trying to execute:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1
(
   ID decimal(11) NOT NULL,
   A varchar2(3) NOT NULL,
   B float(7),
   CONSTRAINT tbl1_pk PRIMARY KEY (ID,A)
)
;

CREATE TABLE tbl2
(
   ID decimal(11) NOT NULL,
   A varchar2(3) NOT NULL,
   B float(15),
   C float(15),
   D char(1) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT tbl2_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID,A,D)
)
;

UPDATE 
  (select tbl1.b, tbl2.c 
   from tbl1 inner join tbl2 
   on tbl1.id=tbl2.id 
   and tbl1.a=tbl2.a 
   and tbl1.b=tbl2.b 
   and tbl1.a='foo' 
   and tbl2.D='a') 
set b=c;
```

How can I define my select such that Oracle will be satisfied that I have no uniqueness violations?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a correlated subquery

```
UPDATE tbl1 t1
   SET t1.b = (SELECT c
                 FROM tbl2 t2
                WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                  AND t1.a  = t2.a
                  AND t1.b  = t2.b
                  AND t2.d  = 'a')
 WHERE t1.a = 'foo'
   AND EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM tbl2 t2
                WHERE t1.id = t2.id
                  AND t1.a  = t2.a
                  AND t1.b  = t2.b
                  AND t2.d  = 'a')
```

The problem with the `UPDATE` that you've written is that Oracle cannot guarantee that there is exactly 1 `tbl2.c` value that corresponds to a single `tbl1.b` value.  If there are multiple rows in `tbl2` for any particular row in `tbl1`, the correlated update is going to throw an error indicating that a single-row subquery returned multiple rows.  In that case, you'd need to add some logic to the subquery to specify which row from `tbl2` to use in that case.

Comment: This appears to solve the problem -- and thanks for the further explanation. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This statement fails with an error (ORA-01779 cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table), because it attempts to modify the base tbl1table, and the tbl1 table is not key-preserved in the  view .
 because although (ID,A) is a key of the dept table, it is not a key of the join.

Comment: The link does not exist anymore, could you please update or summarize the information from the correct page?

Comment: It still exists, but now it is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views.htm#ADMIN11783. It refers to : Oracle 11.2 Database Administrator's Guide ->  § 24 Managing Views, Sequences, and Synonyms -> §§ Key-Preserved Tables

Answer (score 0):

It seems your view is not a key-preserved view according to (http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/updateable%20view.html). Indeed you make your join on not primary key which seems to be not allowed.