# How to get rid of ORA 01779 error :key preserved table

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the sql statement :

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT table1.nbqe as OLD_nbqe, table2.nbqe as NEW_nbqe,
  table1.adr1 as OLD_adr1, table2.adr1 as NEW_adr1
  table1.adr3 as OLD_adr3, table2.adr2 as NEW_adr3
 FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table1.cg= table2.cg AND table1.ce = table2.ce
) t
SET t.OLD_nbqe = t.NEW_nbqe, t.OLD_adr1 = t.NEW_adr1, t.OLD_adr3 = t.NEW_adr3
```

This occurs a 01779 error : cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

How can I modify the sql statement to realize the operation ?

Ty

Note : this question is no duplicate

```
table1 columns :
 nbqe
 adr1
 adr2
 adr3
 cg
 ce

table2 column :
 nbqe
 adr1
 adr2
 cg
 ce
```

in table 2 , cg + ce is a single key

in table 1 you can have several records with the same couple (cg, ce).

no constraints of these tables, not even primary keys or anything.

---

I will ask it differently. The sql statement is probably wrong.

The select inside the update returns the 8 rows of table 1 that should be modified with the value of table2 that can be found in the t table.

How do I update the 8 row sof table1 with the corresponding values of table2 using the table t : is that possible or should I write a big sql statement repeating all the time the same sub query which seems to very strange and not clean.

Comment: The syntax of your update is not correct, please share the table structure and the column you want to update with which values.

Comment: Actually it is a duplicate, say of [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9335536/146325) because the solution to ORA-01779 is standard. You need to fix the inner join so you get one row from `table2` for each row in `table1` or use correlated subqueries instead. However I will give you a chance to explain why it's not a duplicate before closing it.

Comment: Note that we cannot fix the query for you. This error is due to the constraints on your tables and how the business rules apply to the data. It is **your data model**.  You understand the business rules, you can see the data. So you have the necessary information and we don't.

Comment: "should I write a big sql statement repeating all the time the same sub query which seems to very strange and not clean". Said the developer with tables that have no primary keys or constraints of any kind. That, I am afraid, is your problem right there.

Comment: @APC, you probably dont work in computers so you do not know but let me tell you that sometimes you get old programms that are not very clean and you have to do with that..it does not mean you have to continue to work that way.

Comment: The point is, it's unreasonable to expect SQL to work against data which doesn't conform to basic relational principles. Obviously we all work with legacy systems from time to time, and that frequently means we write ugly code. We just have to remember that the ugliness is due to the data structures not the language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092560/ora-01779-cannot-modify-a-column-which-maps-to-a-non-key-preserved-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no more than one row in `table2` corresponding to `table1` then use `merge`:

```
merge into table1 d
using table2 s
on (d.cg = s.cg and d.ce = s.ce)
when matched then update set
    d.nbqe = s.nbqe, d.adr1 = s.adr1, d.adr3 = s.adr3
```

Only matching rows will be updated, rest remains untouched. You could do it with `update`, but this way You avoid repeating condition for `where` clause.

Test:

```
create table table1 (nbqe int, adr1 int, adr2 int, adr3 int, cg int, ce int);
create table table2 (nbqe int, adr1 int, adr2 int, adr3 int, cg int, ce int);

insert into table1 values (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
insert into table1 values (2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2);
insert into table1 values (3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2);

insert into table2 values (5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2);
```

Result:

```
NBQE ADR1 ADR2 ADR3   CG   CE
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ----
   1    1    1    1    1    1
   5    5    2    5    2    2
   5    5    3    5    2    2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET (adr1,adr3,nbqe) =
(SELECT table2.adr1,table2.adr2,table2.nbqe
 FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2
 ON table1.cg= table2.cg AND table1.ce = table2.ce
);
```

also you didn't provide a where clause in your select so all the row successfully joined will be updated, is that what you you want?

Comment: it is not what I want, no where because there is a join.. the select I provided returns 8 rows on the 80. This is what I want

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax - inline view can be updated this way. It's a whole different problem.

Comment: I want to change the eight rows from table 1 not everything

Comment: This is what will happen because of the join, I will update my answer.
You can still run the update, check if it has the expected result, if not just issue a rollback, if it worked as expected then issue a commit

Comment: Your query cannot work because the select returns 8 rowns that you cannot put in a value.

Comment: I updated my answer with you updated query, it will update every row matching your join, the table1 columns will be updated with matching rows from table2