# Cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to run a simple update command to change the base table from this view which is emp.  But I get this error message that I've never seen before and I don't quite understand what it's saying.  I can provide any additional information if needed.

```
UPDATE emp_view_updt SET deptno = 30 WHERE empno = 7369;
```

[image]

Here is the definition of emp_view_updt:

`CREATE VIEW emp_view_updt as 
    SELECT e.empno, e.ename, e.job, d.deptno, 
       DECODE (d.deptno, 10, 'New York', 
                          20, 'Dallas', 
                          30, 'Chicago', 
                          40, 'Boston') as loc 
    FROM emp e INNER JOIN 
         dept d 
         ON e.deptno = d.deptno;`

Here are the columns and data types:
[image]

Here is what the view looks like:
[image]

Comment: can you share the definition/select query of the view emp_view_updt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle - update join - non key-preserved table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335536/oracle-update-join-non-key-preserved-table)

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph I've added that information

Comment: @iminiki not a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing a referential integrity constraint (and possibly a primary key). Make sure `deptno` is the primary key for `dept`, and add a foreign key constraint from `emp` to `dept` and the update should work. This allows the database to infer that each result from the view maps to a distinct row in `dept`.

```
update (select e.empno, e.ename, e.job, d.deptno
        from emp e inner join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno)
set deptno = 30 where empno = 7369;

ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

alter table dept add constraint dept_pk primary key (deptno);

alter table emp add constraint emp_dept_fk foreign key (deptno) references dept (deptno);

update (select e.empno, e.ename, e.job, d.deptno
        from emp e inner join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno)
set deptno = 30 where empno = 7369;

1 row(s) updated.
```

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hm2ybpb8hnjoplqmdfoa4sb56