# updating create view - error ORA-01779:

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've used the CREATE VIEW command to create a view (obviously), and join multiple tables.  The CREATE VIEW command works perfectly, but when I try to update the VIEW RentalInfoOct, I receive error "ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"

```
CREATE VIEW RentalInfoOct
(branch_no, branch_name, customer_no, customer_name, item_no, rental_date)
AS
SELECT i.branchNo, b.branchName, r.customerNo, c.customerName, i.itemNo, r.dateFrom
FROM item i
INNER JOIN rental r
ON i.itemNo = r.itemNo
INNER JOIN branch b
ON i.branchNo = b.branchNo
INNER JOIN customer c
ON r.customerNo = c.customerNo
WHERE r.dateFrom 
BETWEEN to_date('10-01-2009','MM-DD-YYYY')
AND to_date('10-31-2009','MM-DD-YYYY')
```

My update command.

```
UPDATE RentalInfoOct
SET item_no = '3'
WHERE customer_name = 'April Alister'
AND branch_name = 'Kingsway'
AND rental_date = '10/28/2009'
```

I'm not sure if this will help in solving the problem, but here are my CREATE TABLE commands

```
CREATE TABLE Branch
(
    branchNo    SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    branchName  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    branchAddress   VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (BranchNo)
);

--Item Table Definition
CREATE TABLE Item
(
    branchNo    SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    itemNo      SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    itemSize    VARCHAR(8)  NOT NULL,
    price       DECIMAL(6,2)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ItemNo, BranchNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (BranchNo) REFERENCES Branch ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT VALIDAMT
       CHECK (price > 0)
);

-- Customer Table Definition
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    customerNo      SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    customerName        VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    customerAddress     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    customerTel         VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerNo)
);

-- Rental Table Definition
CREATE TABLE Rental
(
    branchNo    SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    customerNo  SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    dateFrom    DATE        NOT NULL,
    dateTo      DATE,
    itemNo      SMALLINT    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (BranchNo, CustomerNo, dateFrom),
    FOREIGN KEY (BranchNo) REFERENCES Branch(BranchNo) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerNo) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerNo) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT CORRECTDATES CHECK (dateTo > dateFrom OR dateTo IS NULL) 
);
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18644258/updating-a-join-view-without-getting-non-key-preserved-error

Answer (score 2):

See: [Oracle: multiple table updates => ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164586/oracle-multiple-table-updates-ora-01779-cannot-modify-a-column-which-maps-t)

You're attempting to update a view with joins, but the join conditions are not based on a uniqueness constraint, which creates the possibility of multiple rows that are created from a single row in one table.

It seems like you need a Unique Key - Foreign Key relationship between the columns your join condition is based on.

EDIT: I just saw your edit. Changing `r.branchNo = b.branchNo` to `i.branchNo = b.branchNo` should go a long way. Not sure how well `r.customerNo = c.customerNo` will work out.

Comment: I implemented the change you suggested, but it still produces the error.  For r.customerNo = c.customerNo, those are the only two tables that have a customerNo column.

Comment: I see the issue now, the following join is not UNIQUE for r:
    `INNER JOIN rental r
    ON i.itemNo = r.itemNo`

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: Well, what are you trying to do? 

I think the logic of your update query might be FUBAR: It's updating the item number of all items rented by `April Alister` at `Kingsway` to `3`.

Comment: It's a homework assignment, the instruction for the question is "Update the view RentalInfoOct, changing April Alister’s rental from Kingsway branch on Oct 28th to item number 3 instead."

Comment: I've changed my update statement to include the date, but I'm still receiving the same error

Comment: Try selecting `r.itemNo` instead of `i.itemNo` in the view declaration. The row `i.itemNo` is a PK and changing it would have unintended consequences. You should ask your professor/teacher about that for more information.

Comment: Try joining from rental on item instead of from item on rental. i.itemNo is UNIQUE also, rental.itemNo should probably be a foreign key that references item.itemNo. You could change this pretty easily by changing the INNER JOIN into an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I've changed it to:

CREATE VIEW RentalInfoOct
(branch_no, branch_name, customer_no, customer_name, item_no, rental_date)
AS
SELECT r.branchNo, b.branchName, r.customerNo, c.customerName, r.itemNo, r.dateFrom
FROM rental r
OUTER JOIN item i
ON r.itemNo = i.itemNo
INNER JOIN branch b
ON r.branchNo = b.branchNo
INNER JOIN customer c
ON r.customerNo = c.customerNo
WHERE r.dateFrom 
BETWEEN to_date('10-01-2009','MM-DD-YYYY')
AND to_date('10-31-2009','MM-DD-YYYY')

However, this produces an error "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"