# Oracle 10g update table i from table 2 column join error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have the following Oracle 10g sql which to me looks about right:

```
update ( select OLD1.TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER,NEW1.PRD_CUST_NUMBER
       FROM  TBYC84_PROFILE_ACCOUNT OLD1,
             TMP_PRD_KEP NEW1
      WHERE 
        OLD1.TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER = NEW1.KEP_CUST_NUMBER )
      SET 
        TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER = PRD_CUST_NUMBER
```

But i am getting this error when i run the script:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
       map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.
```

I have done done some research on this error but not quite sure how to remedy.
So my question is, how can i fix this or is there a better way to write the update sql?

Any help would be appreciated.

many thanks

***UPDATE***
I have changed the update sql to this:

```
update 
  TBYC84_PROFILE_ACCOUNT PA 
set
  (
    PA.TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER
      ) = (
    select
      TPK.PRD_CUST_NUMBER
    from
      TMP_PRD_KEP TPK
    where
      TPK.KEP_CUST_NUMBER = PA.TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER  
     )
```

Now this has updated the TBYC84_PROFILE_ACCOUNT table AND nulled out the TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER
column. 
Why did it do this?
There may be more than one row in the TBYC84_PROFILE_ACCOUNT.TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER
that has the same account number but for different user_id's.
Please can anyone assist in helping me resolve this.
All I need to to is update the TBYC84_PROFILE_ACCOUNT.TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER to the one that is xrefed in the TMP_PRD_KEP, surely this is not impossible.

many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164586/oracle-multiple-table-updates-ora-01779-cannot-modify-a-column-which-maps-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For an UPDATE statement, all the columns that are updated must be extracted from a key-preserved table.*

Also:

*A key-preserved table is one for which every primary key or unique key value in the base table is also unique in the join view.*

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm).

In this case, `TBYC84_PROFILE_ACCOUNT` is being updated. So, it must be key-preserved in the view's subquery. Currently it is not. It must be changed in a way that it becomes key-preserved by involving primary or unique columns in the where clause. If not possible, you should try to update the base table instead.

**UPDATE**

In case of the table update problem, assuming the subquery returns at most one distinct value for the `TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER` column, the reason you get NULLs is that all records are being updated even if they do not have any matching records in the `TMP_PRD_KEP` table. So, the parent update statement needs to be fitted with a where clause:

```
update 
  TBYC84_PROFILE_ACCOUNT PA 
set
  (
    PA.TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER
      ) = (
    select
      TPK.PRD_CUST_NUMBER
    from
      TMP_PRD_KEP TPK
    where
      TPK.KEP_CUST_NUMBER = PA.TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER  
     )
where exists(select * 
             from TMP_PRD_KEP TPK
             where TPK.KEP_CUST_NUMBER = PA.TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER) 
     ;
```

Comment: Ok so the problem I have is that TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER in OLD1 table is not unique and never will be as its part of a composite primary key with a column named TC_PORTAL_ID. So how do i work around this. I need to be able to update all of the TC_CUSTOMER_NUMBER values to referenceing table column NEW1.PRD_CUST_NUMBER

Comment: Then, either all the primary key columns must appear in the `WHERE` clause or if not possible, you should directly update the base table instead of the view:  `UPDATE TBYC84_PROFILE_ACCOUNT OLD1 = ...`

Comment: Please read the updated post which I hope will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a index on the columns used in your where clause predicates. That should solve your problem.